# JQuery $.ajax callback works in FF and Safari, but not IE

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I'm using jQuery to query a database and update a table of bid and ask prices for a currency trading ticker. I'm using $.ajax to send a currency symbol to a php script that queries the database and returns a xml document that javascript parses to make updates to the table. Everything is working in FireFox on both pc/mac and on Safari, but doesn't work in IE. The relevant code...

The jQuery making the ajax call:

```
var updateDataFunction = function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "func2.php",
        type: "GET",
        data: "symbol=<?php echo $stock; ?>",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (msg) {
            var bid = $('bid',msg).text();
            var ask = $('ask',msg).text();
            var spread = $('spread',msg).text();

            // do some other stuff
        }
});
};
```

The script uses php to place the stock in the javascript before the javascript is run. The updateDataFunction gets called in a $(document).ready.

The php script

```
<?php
header("content-type:text/xml;charset=utf-8");

// connect to the database

function GetUpdate($symbol) {

$query = "SELECT * FROM tblSG WHERE strSymbol='$symbol'";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $spread= $row['fBid'] - $row['fAsk'];
    $output="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>\n<exchange>\n";
    $output.="<bid>" . number_format($row['fBid'],4) . "</bid>\n";
    $output.="<ask>" . number_format($row['fAsk'],4) . "</ask>\n";
    $output.="<spread>" . number_format($spread,4) . "</spread>\n";
    $output.="</exchange>";
}

return $output;

}


$symbol = $_GET['symbol'];

echo GetUpdate($symbol);

?>
```

Using POST instead of GET causes it to fail in FF and Safari as well. Any ideas on a solution to this?

Comment: I assume when you change it to POST, you are changing your PHP code to $_POST.  You can use $_REQUEST so that the server side doesn't need to know if it's a post or get.  As far as the error goes, do you get a JS error?

Comment: Are you using Fiddler (http://www.fiddler2.com/)? What's the response from the server?

Comment: Add this parameter to your $.ajax call:

error: function(r,e){ alert(e); }

This will let you know if there was any error.  My guess is that IE will return a popup saying 'parsererror' and other browsers will continue to work fine.

Comment: Yes, when I changed it from GET to POST it was changed in both the javascript and the php.

Comment: Installed Fiddler2 and the response I get from the server is a HTTP/1.1 200 OK. The raw response has the text/xml header aswell, but the generated XML is appearing in the RAW tab of Fiddler and not the XML one. Adding the error alert code did not pop up a error message on loading the page.

Answer (score 2):

OK, using the suggested Fiddler app to check the server responses I noticed it was hitting the server, but only once while in FireFox it was hitting the server every two seconds as it is supposed to. Because of the short update interval I never noticed the update in IE. Upon further investigation, IE apparently caches all GET requests and re-serves the old request if the same request is made later. To prevent this, you have to send header info to the browser to not cache the result. Adding the following code to the php script below the content-type declaration resolved the issue:

```
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```